# $_GET array is empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3

My Kohana 3 application makes use of a fair bit of $_GET parameters. However when I deployed the application I got a blank page with just the text "No input file specified". I quickly found the solution to this seemingly common problem by changing in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L]
```

However now my $_GET array has lost all the parameters passed. Any page that doesn't require $_GET is working fine. I'm not too good with .htaccess files, but from what I can tell, adding the ? has replaced the $_GET array with the uri.

I've also tried

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/?$0 [PT,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

but to no avail.

Below is my .htaccess file in full (mostly the same as example.htaccess)

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L]
```

The closest I've found to a solution was this post:
http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/4857/#Comment_4857
However that seems to be for an older version of Kohana, and I'm not sure how this would work in Kohana v3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `QSA` (Query String Append) should help:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?$0 [PT,L, QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect, so simple. You just made my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have to make two changes to the K03 example.htaccess to get it to work:

`RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system)/ - [F,L]` instead of

`RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]` (which gives an Internal Server Error)

`RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` instead of

`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]` (which gives a No input file specified message.)

Here is my .htaccess file for K03:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
#RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system)/ - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Strangely enough, this solution also worked when I just changed that last line to `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`

Comment: @jord - that's the only way I could get rid of the 500 error I was having - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly the same error, which I think is caused by the fact that my apache is working in fastcgi mode.
Any from above solution with htaccess rules worked for me, but searching over the web I find this rule:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

and just replace with it the old one:
`RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`